# sql query - Get the difference time between swipe in - Swipe out for employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

swipe_details

```
EMPID   EVENT_TYPE   Swipe_time
1       EN           2012-06-01 12:00
1       EX           2012-06-01 12:30
2       EN           2012-06-01 12:50
1       EN           2012-06-01 13:10
2       EX           2012-06-01 13:30
2       EN           2012-06-01 14:00
2       EX           2012-06-01 19:00
1       EX           2012-06-01 19:30
```

which basically stores the swipe details of employees (where EN is "Swipe-IN" and EX is "Swipe OUT")

**I want to find out the EMPIDs who spend maximum time in the office for a given time frame.
So my input will be a start time and end time (Ex: 2012-06-01 12:30 and 2012-06-05 18:30).**

Please note these 3 conditions as well:

1. There could be employees who have entered office before the time
   frame. In this case we have to consider the swipe in as the
   beginning of the time frame for that employee.
2. Same way for employees who exit after the time frame, the swipe out time would be the end of the time frame.
3. IF there are employees whose swipe in time is less than the time frame and swipe out time is greater than the time frame, then all of
   these empIDs should be shown as the result

What is the best way to do it? Is it possible with a single query?

Comment: What do you do if the first occurrence within a time frame is an EX?

Comment: I see you have tagged both MySQL and SQL Server.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @Kevin : I am using SQL server 2008

Comment: @egrunin: there is an update : If the  first occurrence within a time frame is an EX, then you should consider the start time of the time frame as the swipe-in time for caluculation(Please refer #1 in the question) . Sorry I told you that you can ignore that record , I misunderstood your question. my mistake..appologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select    empid,
          sum
          (
              datediff
              (
              MINUTE, 
              case when timesheet.timein < @timeframe_start 
                  then @timeframe_start  
                  else timesheet.timein end, 
              case when timesheet.timeout > @timeframe_end 
                  then @timeframe_end 
                  else timesheet.timeout end
              )
          ) as total_duration
from     (
         select    timein.empid, 
                   timein.swipe_time as timein, 
                   timeout.swipe_time as timeout
         from      tbltest timein
         left join tblTest timeout 
         on        timein.empid = timeout.empid
         and       timeout.eventtype = 'ex'
         and       timeout.swipe_time = 
             (
             select     MIN(swipe_time) 
             from       tblTest tcheck 
             where      tcheck.empid = timeout.empid 
             and        tcheck.eventtype = 'EX' 
             and        tcheck.swipe_time > timein.swipe_time
             )
         where      timein.eventtype = 'en'
         ) timesheet
where    timesheet.timein between @timeframe_start and @timeframe_end
or       timesheet.timeout between @timeframe_start and @timeframe_end
or       (
         timesheet.timein < @timeframe_start 
         and timesheet.timeout > @timeframe_end
         )
group by empid
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: just change tblTest to your table name.

Comment: You really dislike vertical scrolling, do you... :)

Comment: haha! yes - i suppose i do! why waste all that paper at the bottom... ;)

Comment: Here's a SQLFiddle for you to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54e6f/3 (I changed one of your parameters, though)

Comment: @SeanW : Thank you for your answer. I am verifying it with my table.. Please give some time for feedback